# OOP: Is it normal to have a lot of inherited classes?

Tags: class, methods

I started writing some code for a 2D game, created a class "objets" trying to keep it as generic as possible. I have a few methods and attributes that are common to every kind of element (buldings, ppl, interface buttons, etc) like (w, h, x, y ...you know) but most of them only make sense when applied to and specific type of item.
So I would have to inherit a new class for every type of actor in the game?
Just wondering if this is a common practice, or maybe i should manage it in a different way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're introducing behaviour then subclass, however if the difference is attribute based then don't e.g.

Animal (has .colour and .makeSound) -> Dog (has .eatOwnPoop) -> RedDog (no, too specific, covered by colour)

Notice how I had ".makeSound" in Animal. I could have put .bark in dog, but then I'd have to put .meow in cat etc. The subclass can simply override and provide a concrete sound.

However, you can use interfaces to better cross-cut your code, but that's quite a lengthy topic and probably overkill for your needs (although it could help any unit testing you do).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are over-using inheritance. It is certainly a red flag when you simultaneously say "common attributes like ..." and "...only make sense when applied to a specific type." Also, it is a red flag that domain objects such as `building` share a common base class with an interface object like `button`. Finally, it is quite unusual to define your own `objet` (`object`?) class from which every class in your system derives. It's not inconceivable, but in combination with your other comments, it sounds like you've started down an unproductive path.

You might want to refer to a good tutorial on object-oriented design and analysis such as "[Head First OOA&D](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596008678)"

Answer (score 0):

You do not HAVE to do anything. Generally, it is useful to use derived classes if they exhibit some kind of commonality but become more specialised in nature requiring specific functionality at each level of inheritance. It is also good to use if you want to have polymorphic behaviour. You have asked a very open ended question but basically do not feel that you HAVE to use inheritance as not every problem requires it and indeed some people overuse inheritance, introducing it in places where it really is not needed. All in all, I would really recommend that if you haven't already that you read a good book on object oriented design as this will then get you to think about your code from a different perspective and greatly improve the way you view software and design it. It may sound like a cop out but this kind of question is very hard to answer without knowing all details of what you are doing.